# jquery selector on click not working

Tags: jquery, html

I have an html page:-

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
                       <li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#Info">Info</a></li>
                       <li><a data-toggle="tab" id="ViewTable" href="#view">View Details</a>
                    </ul>
```

My Jquery code is:-

```
$("#ViewTable").on('click', function (e) {
                 $('.modal-footer .btn-danger').prop("disabled", true);
               });
```

My above code is not working can anybody tell me why?

Comment: What is the JQuery version you're using?

Comment: It would be better if you share Directive code and its usage seems XY problem

Comment: Closed as duplicate because you state that a delegated event handler fixed the issue. See the dupe question for a thorough explanation of the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this

```
  $(document).on('click', "#ViewTable", function (e) {
      $('.btn-danger').prop("disabled", true);
  });
```

Or else like

```
  $("#ViewTable").click(function (e) {
      $('.btn-danger').prop("disabled", true);
  });
```

For more on [jQuery.on](http://api.jquery.com/on/#on-events-selector-data)

**Updated:** We use `document`, a parent element which holds the entire `DOM`. We bind event to the parent element `document` and then select the proper `#ViewTable` element in the `DOM` tree we want. This approach is helpful for dynamically created `DOM` elements.

Comment: first one worked,but why you used 'document' selector, can u explain?

Comment: @shreyagupta Yes, updated it

Comment: ok, but here which elements are creating dynamically? The nav tabs or button etc. are present before the event triggers. Also I updated the question. Can u check that too.

Comment: Even your elements are static, I think Angular library reconstructs the `DOM` based on the `ng-` attributes. Since you have `ng-show` attribute which is a condition for angular whether to show or hide the underlying elements(`#ViewTable`). Then we can say that your elements are dynamic at `DOM` level.